# Minimizing the maximal residual in mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

With this:

```
d1 = 10; d2 = 4;
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d1, d2}];
vec = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, d1];
```

`LeastSquares[mat, vec]` returns the `x`, that minimizes `Plus @@ ((mat.x-vec)^2)`

What is the best way to make mathematica return the `x` that minimizes `Max @@ ((mat.x-vec)^2)`

I ended up with this, thank you Daniel ;)

```
With[{L = Length[First[mat]]},
LinearProgramming[Prepend[ConstantArray[0, L], 1],
Prepend[#, 1] & /@ Riffle[mat, -mat], Riffle[vec, -vec],
Prepend[ConstantArray[-\[Infinity], L], 0]]]
```

Comment: Nice. I might "borrow" (okay, steal) this next time I want to use `LinearProgramming` directly and avoid `NMinimize` overhead. I'd give it an upvote but I notice I already did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to minimize the absolute values. This can be set up as an explicit linear programming problem. The advantage over the approach of @bobthechemist (which is good, and I voted up) is that the problem can then be shipped to special case LP code.

```
vars = Array[x, d2];
linearexprs = mat.vars - vec;
constraints = 
  Join[Thread[max >= linearexprs], Thread[max >= -linearexprs]];
NMinimize[{max, constraints}, Join[{max}, vars]]

(* Out[790]= {0.634141, {max -> 0.634141, x[1] -> 0.679669, 
  x[2] -> 0.244346, x[3] -> -0.539059, x[4] -> -1.09431}} *)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you, I tried to set this up with LinearProgramming[], but I think it's not possible, do you think I'm wrong?

Comment: It can be set up to use LinearProgramming directly, but that's usually more work than I'm willing to do. Maybe someone out there has a program to convert an LP in `NMinimize` format to one directly usable by `LinearProgramming`? Of course then you'd be essentially replicating work that `NMinimize` does in coming up with that conversion itself.

Answer (score 1):

Since `LeastSquares` can be written as

```
NMinimize[Plus @@ ((mat.{x1, x2, x3, x4} - vec)^2), {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

Then you can use a similar approach to minimizing your desired function:

```
NMinimize[Max @@ ((mat.{x1, x2, x3, x4} - vec)^2), {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

Although whether or not this is the "best" way is likely up for debate.